# Approach for exporting the .csv data to excel workbook

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I was trying to import data set to excel via creating a temporary .csv file in between to speed up the process.

Approach used:

1. Create a .csv file with the required data.
2. Open this .csv file using OpenText() function and save it as exel file.
3. Delete the temp. created .csv file.

Now the problem is when user opts for export to workbook option in that case i had to keep the newly created workbook open to the user as per my application requirement. But since as per my approach file is still opened in the excel workbook. So it's not allowing me the delete the temporary .csv file for obvious reason.

Can anyone suggest me another approach to do this. For exporting i had to use .csv option only, using library closedXML is not in the picture here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the .csv is not a requirement, take a look at using [EPPlus](http://codeplex.epplus.com) for creating the Excel file directly without the in-between step.

Comment: You could use oledb. See this article http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/705470/Read-and-Write-Excel-Documents-Using-OLEDB

Comment: Sorry, I had the URL incorrect. It's epplus.codeplex.com. If you're in any sort of web environment, you do not want to use OleDb. There are a few issues to do deal with there on a server environment, and you need to install additional items on the server.